# How to transfer SOL in anchor smart contract instruction

Tags: rust, solana, anchor-solana

I am creating a dapp where multiple users can deposit SOL into an event account, and depending on whoever wins the event, they can redeem SOL back to their wallet.

How can I transfer native SOL (not any other spl-token) directly into the event account's vault address in an anchor smart contract instruction?

Would the following anchor instruction work?
If yes, what should be the `PROGRAM_ACCOUNT` in the following? Presumably, it should be the account that handles native SOL, but I couldn't find it in the documentation.

```
token::transfer(
    CpiContext::new(
        PROGRAM_ACCOUNT,
        anchor_spl::token::Transfer {
            from: source_user_info,
            to: destination_user_info,
            authority: source_user_info,
        },
    ),
    1,
)?;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please the reference for account definition and initialization of program?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To send native SOL using Anchor, you can use the following code inside an instruction:

```rust
    let ix = anchor_lang::solana_program::system_instruction::transfer(
        &ctx.accounts.from.key(),
        &ctx.accounts.to.key(),
        amount,
    );
    anchor_lang::solana_program::program::invoke(
        &ix,
        &[
            ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.to.to_account_info(),
        ],
    );
```

Where amount is a number (u64) representing the [Lamports](https://docs.solana.com/introduction#what-are-sols) (0.000000001 SOL).

You can check the [Transfer](https://docs.rs/solana-program/1.6.1/solana_program/system_instruction/fn.transfer.html) function in the Solana Program documentation and the [Solana Cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/) section of [Sending SOL](https://solanacookbook.com/recipes/basic-transactions.html#sending-sol).

Comment: can you please provide us with a full contract code? How do you define `from` and `to` accounts. WhenI tried to provide `to` account, the test has failed because it required `to` account to belong to program itself. best :)

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, all of the answers thus far are for plain Solana, not Anchor.

Anchor already comes with additional conveniences to make transfers easier. You were on the right track with the code in the question:

```rust
use anchor_lang::system_program;

let cpi_context = CpiContext::new(
    ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(), 
    system_program::Transfer {
        from: ctx.accounts.account_a.clone(),
        to: ctx.accounts.account_b.clone(),
    });
system_program::transfer(cpi_context, bid_amount)?;
```

This is assuming this accounts struct:

```rust
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct MyInstruction<'info> {
    account_a: AccountInfo<'info>,
    account_b: AccountInfo<'info>,
}
```

Of course, if you are using `Account<>` wrappers, just replace `clone()` with `to_account_info()`.

Comment: Thanks for this @sohrab! Do you know how can we add a Memo to the transaction? (the anchor way)

Comment: Acheron made the Anchor wrapper for Memo: https://github.com/acheroncrypto/native-to-anchor/tree/master/client/packages/spl-memo

Answer (score 1):

For native SOL, you'll have to do something a bit different, calling `system_instruction::transfer` with the system program, and not the SPL token program.

There isn't a handy wrapper in Anchor (that I can find), so here's an example of doing it without Anchor: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/78cb32435296eb258ec3de76ee4ee2d391f397ee/associated-token-account/program/src/tools/account.rs#L29

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like this

```
let lamports: u64  = 1000000;

let sol_transfer = anchor_lang::solana_program::system_instruction::transfer(
    &ctx.accounts.from.key,
    &ctx.accounts.to.key,
    lamports,
);
invoke(
    &sol_transfer,
    &[
        ctx.accounts.from.clone(),
        ctx.accounts.to.clone(),
        ctx.accounts.system_program.clone(),
    ],
)?;
```

Also, make sure to pass system_program to your program. For example

```
 #[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SolSend<'info> {
    #[account(mut, signer)]
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    pub from: AccountInfo<'info>,       
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    #[account(mut)]
    pub to: AccountInfo<'info>,        
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we don't read or write from this account
    pub system_program: AccountInfo<'info>,
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

To send native SOL with Anchor

```rs
#[program]
pub mod learn_solana_anchor {
    use super::*;

    pub fn transfer_native_sol(ctx: Context<Transfer>) -> Result<()> {
        let amount_of_lamports = 42; // could be an argument ;-)
        let from = ctx.accounts.from.to_account_info();
        let to = ctx.accounts.to.to_account_info();

        // Debit from_account and credit to_account
        **from.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= amount_of_lamports;
        **to.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += amount_of_lamports;

        Ok(())
    }

}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Transfer<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because its just a stackoverflow sample o.O
    pub from: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    /// CHECK: This is not dangerous because we just pay to this account
    pub to: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account()]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

### Ref

https://solanacookbook.com/references/programs.html#how-to-transfer-sol-in-a-program